# create requirements.txt for scripts folder

Tags: python, scripting, pip

I need create a requierment.txt for all scripts in specific folder(s). For your informations, scripts are used by an other program and run inside it... I can't use venv because program use it own install python. I run pip in *.bat to specify python path in PATH.

Do you know if a package python exist and can output a list of packages use in scripts grouped in specific folder it contains python (an other but ignore it) file with retroingenieering source file?

for example:

```
pip_local freeze -py-env="c:\program\bin\py27\python.exe" -script-path="c:\program\scripts"
```

"scripts" contains module script and "local lib class package"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `requirements.txt` convention isn't used for bare modules in a directory. There is no way to reference a module by path name in a requirements file. Requirements files are meant to state a module's globally unique name and version number, where "globally unique" is relative to all the repositories you've enabled for pip -- PyPi by default, and others via for example `--find-links`.

You could create your modules as installable packages (via `setup.py` or some other mechanism) and making them available to install from PyPi, a private PyPi-ish server (like Gemfury), or directly from GitHub, Bitbucket or other SCC.  Those all work with the normal requirements file mechanism.